# Why i am i getting an sqlexception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement error

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to build a login form and I get an error when I try introduce a catch statement here is the code

```
 try {
     cnx = datasource.getConnection();
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(" Get Connection -> " + My_CNX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
 return cnx;
```

Comment: I'm retagging this as `java`.  I don't think this is `javascript`.

Comment: I assume that the `getConnection()` method that you are calling is not declared to throw SQLException.  Check the API documentation.

Comment: Agreeing with the @DaveCosta, check the doc. what is the datasource object?